# Given matrices $A$ and $B$, solve for $Z$ in the following equation: $A^{-4}BZ^{3}A^{5}B^{2}A=-3A^{-6}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -4 & 3\\
4 & -1 & 2\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -4 & 5\\
1 & -2 & 3\\
-2 & 3 & -4\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Solve Z in the following equation: $A^{-4}BZ^{3}A^{5}B^{2}A=-3A^{-6}$.

I tried this way:

$A^{-4}BZ^{3}A^{5}B^{2}A=-3A^{-6}$

$\Leftrightarrow BZ^{3}A^{5}B^{2}A=-3A^{-2}$

$\Leftrightarrow Z^{3}A^{5}B^{2}A=-3B^{-1}A^{-2}$

$\Leftrightarrow Z^{3}A^{5}B^{2}=-3B^{-1}A^{-3}$

$\Leftrightarrow Z^{3}A^{5}=-3B^{-1}A^{-3}B^{-2}$

$\Leftrightarrow Z^{3}=-3B^{-1}A^{-3}B^{-2}A^{-5}$

But in  the final equation, $B^{-1}$ does not exist so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem wasn't meant to be solved. Whoever set this question probably wanted you to point out that the equation is insolvable, because the LHS is singular (as $B$ is singular) but the RHS is not.